# JSON object from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am trying to make a call to api which returns json object

```
 { "category" : [ { "id" : 5,
    "name" : "Bollywood"
  },
  { "id" : 484,
    "name" : "International"
  },
  { "id" : 15,
    "name" : "Devotional"
  }
 ]}
```

1. How do I make a call from within my html page javascript.

Please note: I cannot use jquery, simple javascript is needed..

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: [There's no such thing as a JSON Object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: lmgtfy links have been blocked by SO or else would have given a nice link. ;)

Comment: So how are you requesting the JSON, and what do you want to do with the JSON?

Comment: @artlung I am calling an api, say twitter api. Which returns this id, name pair. I need to populate this list into dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. How do I make a call from within my html page javascript... Um... what API is this? If it's javascript... why don't you just call the function...
2. Why don't you use javascript `document.createElement("select")` and `getAttribute()` and `setAttribute()`
   https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createElement http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getattribute.asp

Alternatively you could just create the code with javascript as a string and set `.innerHTML` of some element (like a div)

1. Attach an event handler with aforementioned `setAttribute('onchange', "some_function_name")` or something

I haven't give you a very detailed response because you haven't given a very good quesiton

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make an xmlhttprequest, then you have to parse the json string so that it is a javascript object.

Douglas Crockford's JSON-js can parse json strings for you https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

You will need an onChange event listener on your dropdown.

You should look at the jquery source code for the .on function that should give you some insight has to how to response to events as DOM elements are added dynamically.